# String in Message body not working

Tags: iphone, nsstring, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I implemented the code below, and logged the `arrayPlainText` but when I run it in the simulator and on my iPhone it only shows the first item and everything else just disappeared.

```
NSMutableArray *xmlListContent;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[self returnListPath]])
    {
        xmlListContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self returnListPath]];
        NSMutableArray *listContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < [xmlListContent count]; i++)
        {
            MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            [mailComposer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
            if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
                [mailComposer setSubject:editedListTitle];
                [mailComposer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
                NSString *item = [NSString stringWithString:[[xmlListContent objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"label"]];
                NSString *tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@",item];
                [listContent addObject:tempString];

                NSString *arrayPlainText = [listContent componentsJoinedByString:@"<br>"];
                [mailComposer setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html>%@</html>",arrayPlainText] isHTML:YES];
                DLog(arrayPlainText);

                [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        xmlListContent = [NSMutableArray array];
        DLog(@"failed to compose list via email");
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide more code? You're using variables of which you're not showing us their declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is here.

```
NSMutableArray *xmlListContent;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[self returnListPath]])
{
    xmlListContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self returnListPath]];
    NSMutableArray *listContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < [xmlListContent count]; i++)
    {
        NSString *item = [[xmlListContent objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"label"];
        NSString *tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@", item];
        [listContent addObject:tempString];
    }

    NSString *arrayPlainText = [listContent componentsJoinedByString:@"<br>\n"];
    DLog(arrayPlainText);

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [mailComposer setMailComposeDelegate:self];

        [mailComposer setSubject:editedListTitle];
        [mailComposer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];

        [mailComposer setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html>%@</html>",arrayPlainText] isHTML:YES];

        [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        xmlListContent = [NSMutableArray array];
        DLog(@"failed to compose list via email");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this code:

```
NSString *item = [NSString stringWithString:[[self.array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"label"]];
NSString *tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@",item];
[listContent addObject:tempString];

NSString *arrayPlainText = [listContent componentsJoinedByString:@"<br>"];
[mailComposer setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html>%@</html>",arrayPlainText] isHTML:YES];
DLog(arrayPlainText);
```

Comment: If you print content of arrayPlainText does it contain all the value?

Comment: Yeah, it has everything full output, but when it is in the composer it doesn't.